# linker error MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I have problem compiling my MPI Console app I add the include & lib file but I have this errors
[image]

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Comm_size referenced in function _main   
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Comm_rank referenced in function _main       Helloworld_mpi
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Init referenced in function _main        
Helloworld_mpi
Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link with your MPI import library. If you are using Microsoft MPI, it is called `msmpi.lib`. You can do this in two ways:

1. Somewhere in one of yours cpp files write the following: `#pragma comment (lib, "msmpi.lib")`
2. Open your project properties, go to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and add `msmpi.lib` to that list.